# Electron desktop app Icon is not displaying?

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-packager

I am creating an electron app in windows. Everything is working fine but when I run the setup, the desktop shortcut icon is electron's icon.
This is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "happiness",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "icon": "logomain.ico",
  "iconUrl":"file:///E:/abc/abc1/logomain.ico",
  "description": "Descriptions",
  "main": "index.js",
  "build": {
    "appID": "happiness",
    "productName": "happiness",
    "icon": "logomain.ico"
},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-packager": "^13.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "electron-winstaller": "^2.7.0"
  }
}
```

I am using `Electron windows installer` to generate final `exe` and this is my `build.js` file:

```
var electronInstaller = require('electron-winstaller');
// In this case, we can use relative paths
var settings = {
    appDirectory: './release-builds/app-happiness-win32-ia32',
    outputDirectory: './myapp-source-built-installers',
    authors: 'ABC',
    exe: './app-happiness.exe',
    setupIcon: 'logomain.ico'
};
resultPromise = electronInstaller.createWindowsInstaller(settings);   
resultPromise.then(() => {
    console.log("The installers of your application were succesfully created !");
}, (e) => {
    console.log(`Well, sometimes you are not so lucky: ${e.message}`)
});
```

However the icon is displaying in `control panel` and  in the `startup menu`. But in shortcut of the app electron's icon is displaying.
This is the command I'm using:

```
electron-packager . app-happiness --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName="Happiness" --electron-version=4.0.0 --icon=logomain.ico
```

and then

```
node build.js
```

Comment: Need help. Can you please share the process how you created the setup

Comment: I am stuck at the same point. Has anyone figured this out a year later?